# Learning Powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

I am a young I.T Apprentice who is responsible (in part)for administering Active Directory tasks.

I have looked to learn powershell to help with this.

Anyway, I'm looking to incorporate reading data from files into my daily tasks to simplify a process, I'm looking to pull data and configure Changes for multiple AD accounts. My idea is to have a file with the samaccountname listed in a single column (with no header). Import the csv file to get the ad username and disable the users then place a new description in the accounts description field.

Right now I have a csv with usernames listed and a script that imports the csv and this is where I'm stuck.

I can execute the disable-aduser and set-aduser -description "sample text", functions I need for the script separately , successfully in testing in a one liner situation by calling on the get-aduser and piping the result to each command, but I'm looking to place this in a script and grab the ad usernames from a csv for multiple accounts.

I'm having trouble setting the object variable from the csv (i hope that's the right terminology), I have been unable to 'get this' for lack of a better term. I'm hoping to place this into a for loop to include the functions I have described.

Can anyone help me or describe how I can set the variables to encapsulate each ad user account in my file to help me continue on with my script and configure the changes above?

I know this may seem like a strange or overly simple question to ask I.T pros but I can assure you I have done further reading but I havent been able to find a resolution to this specific problem.

My apologies if the terminology in my question is not spot on.

Thank you in advance, Glenn.

Comment: pretty sure you are looking for `import-csv` and `foreach-object` cmdlets

Comment: posting your code would make the discussion _far_ more to-the-point. [*grin*] however, a general outline is to look at loop structures like for, foreach, & foreach-object.

Comment: Watch "powershell in a month of lunches" on YouTube. It will get you started right. If your company has an account for cbt nuggets, pluralsight, or itpro.tv you could learn there. If not I'd recommend asking for them to pay for one for the team. It won't be super expensive and it only helps.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to loop thru a collection of items imported from a CSV file ...

```
# fake reading in a headerless, one-column text file as a CSV
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$UserNameList = @'
OneTest
TwoTest
ThreeTest
FourTest
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header UserName

foreach ($UNL_Item in $UserNameList)
    {
    # do the things you need done to each user id here
    'Acting on user [ {0} ] ...' -f $UNL_Item.UserName
    }
```

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: Thanks Lee sorry for the lack of info. I have roughly this in mind from memory import-csv "c:\path to File.csv"  ForEach-Object { Disable-ADAccount Set-ADUser -description "test description" } that's essentially it but I know I haven't set the variable correctly for each ad name in the CSV to be processed. Do I also have to get-aduser within curly brackets or with the ForEach-Object loop pick up the ad username object from csv?

Comment: @GlennR - the example i show would use `$UNL_Item.UserName` to refer to the current item in the loop. i don't have any access to the AD stuff, so i can't test what parameter the username would go with - it's likely `-Identity $UNL_Item.UserName -Descritpion $YourInfoHere`.

Answer (score 0):

The below will load the entire CSV and show it in an `Out-GridView`. You can then CTRL click multiple users and process them that way.

I enjoy doing it this way in the event that another name has snuck into my CSV when it should not have,

```
Import-CSV 'C:\Location\of\CSV.csv' | Out-GridView -PassThru | ForEach-Object{Disable-ADAccount $_.SamAccountName; Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Description "Test Description"}
```

NOTE: Thanks Robert for advice of skipping putting the `Import-csv` into a variable to handle and going straight to the source.